# Material UI permanent drawer covers the navbar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-jsx

I don't know why the Drawer component does not obey the styling rules I specified. I.e., its width it not 17rem, on the one hand, and, I don't know why it exceeds its parent component borders, on the other hand. Here is the interesting code from the application:

```
const styles = {
  background: {
    display: 'flex',
    //flexDirection: 'row',
    height: '100vh',
    width: '100vw',
    backgroundColor: '#303030',
  },
  drawer: {
    width: '17rem',
  },
  toolbar: {
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  titles: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    cursor: 'pointer',
  },
  btn: {
    color: 'inherit',
    outline: 'none',
    fontWeight: 500,
  },
}

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <AppBar style={{ position: 'relative', zIndex: '1201' }}>
        <Toolbar style={styles.toolbar}>
          <div style={styles.titles}>
            <Typography variant='h5'>
              Naughty pie
            </Typography>
            <Typography sx={{marginLeft: '1rem'}}>
              @0.0.0
            </Typography>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Button style={styles.btn}>
                <GroupIcon style={{ margin: '2px' }} />
                USERS
            </Button>
              ...
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <div style={styles.background}>
        <Drawer variant='permanent' style={styles.drawer}>
          <List>
            <ListItemButton>
              <ListItemText primary='All Messages' />
            </ListItemButton>
          </List>
        </Drawer>
      </div> 
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code.

```html
import {
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
  Button,
  Drawer,
  List,
  ListItemButton,
  ListItemText,
  Box,
} from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  const drawerWidth = "17rem";
  return (
    <>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          height: "100vh",
          width: "100vw",
          backgroundColor: "red",
        }}
      >
        <AppBar
          position="fixed"
          sx={{ zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1 }}
        >
          <Toolbar>
            <Box>
              <Typography variant="h5">Naughty pie</Typography>
              <Typography>@0.0.0</Typography>
            </Box>

            <Button variant="contained" color="success">
              USERS
            </Button>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>

        <Drawer
          open
          variant="permanent"
          sx={{
            width: drawerWidth,
            flexShrink: 0,
            [`& .MuiDrawer-paper`]: {
              width: drawerWidth,
              boxSizing: "border-box",
            },
          }}
        >
          <Toolbar />
          <List>
            <ListItemButton>
              <ListItemText primary="All Messages" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </List>
        </Drawer>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do? first of all, I should say it's better to use a Box (import it from "@mui/material") component instead of a div HTML tag when you are using MUI  and use an sx prop instead of a style prop

after that, look at your Drawer component, It has a "styles" prop, it is not correct, it should be style if you use it.

please give me more details about something you want to do.

Comment: Good point, indeed, the style prop isn't correct - now I edited the code. But the real problem is that my sidebar created with the help of drawer component is placed at the top of the page, not under the app bar as I want.

Comment: I will put the code fragment in the next answer, look at this.